# Magento 2 Indexer Allowed memory size of xxxx bytes exhausted

Tags: magento2, indexer

When running the Magento 2 indexer process from the CLI with command:

```
./magento indexer:reindex customer_grid
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 280224918230723 bytes) in /www/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
```

The number of bites it tries to allocate is unrealistic. so increasing the memory limit is no option ( Also I think 1GB is already way too much.

I tried manually setting the index to invalid via the database and retrying to index. but this does not change anything. I also can’t find a matching table in the DB to flus as this did solve the problem in Magento 1.x.

The server runs on PHP version 7.0.0 and MariaDB version 10.1.9

Comment: try ./magento -d memory_limit=2048M indexer:reindex customer_grid. I had the same problem and this worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug (a memory leak) in PHP 7.
PHP 7 is not ready yet to run such a complex software like Magento 2: you will get a lot of segfaults, memory leaks, etc.
I recommend to check it again in a month, may be it will be fixed in PHP 7.

Comment: We have downgraded to PHP 5.6 This indeed solved the above problem and lots of other issues we had. Thx!

Answer (score 7):

Try this, it will take memory in run time:

For Linux

> -dmemory_limit=2G magento indexer:reindex

For Windows as well as Linux

> php -dmemory_limit=2G magento indexer:reindex

Comment: Hi Yogesh,

Thanks for the suggestion. But as I stated in my initial question. Giving 2GB to a script is a bit extreme.... Also I am running all sites on PHP 7.0.7 which also solved the problem.

Comment: I mean its and one time solutions, i faced the same but after allocating memory size within the query on fly worked for me.. please post if you got anything on the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but there is a patch for this issue

https://gist.github.com/mpchadwick/a627b4fe6e5299cd3e8f1fdf57cf9b6c

It is also fixed in core if you upgrade to 2.2.X

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/6d98e2a57059ef75d9d0dd0585b84bb33953e107